# Disable long click in android webview

Tags: android, android-webview, onlongclicklistener, long-click

I am using css columns to display contents in android webview. I used longclicklistner {return true}; with this I was able to disable longclick in phones but it doesn't seem to work in tabs(eg galaxy tab 2). I'm also preventing touchmove event using jquery but the css columns are moving when swipe occurs as part of longclick. Any help is welcome. Thank you.

```
wbView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    wbView.setLongClickable(false);
```

jquery code:

```
document.getElementById("divIdToShowContent").ontouchmove = function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         var touching = null;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I avoided using GestureDetector and SimpleOnGestureListener, I done it with catching touch listnerby catching the position fron MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and MotionEvent.ACTION_UP

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `GestureDetector`, the `SimpleOnGestureListener` has `onSingleTapConfirmed()` for click events and `onFling()` for swipe events.

Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html)

Comment: onSingleTapConfirmed() is not being called when long click and text selection occurs, I checked it with the help of Logs. The function onDown() is called, could not distinguish click and long click

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
_webview.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    return true;
}
});
```